# Java String split() delimiter for zero length values

Tags: java, string, delimiter, zero

I would like to split the following string generated from a database resultset row.

Sample rows:

A) (74,"and there","is a car","in the","garage man",t)

B) (17,account3,,,,t)

I want an output as follows (Pipe | to separate split elements):

A) 74 | and there | is a car | in the | garage man | t

B) 17 | account3 | | | | t

I want to zero length values to be stored as null in my application. This is my source code:

```
public void refreshSearchTable (ArrayList<String> newData){
        int noOfRows = newData.size();
        int noOfColumns = gui.getTableSearchResultHeader().length + 1;
        Object[][] tempList = new Object[noOfRows][noOfColumns];
        String rowResult = "";
        String delims = "[,()\"]+";
        String [] tokens;
        Object [] elements = newData.toArray();

        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < noOfRows; i++){
            rowResult = elements[i].toString();
            System.out.println("rowresult: " + rowResult);
            tokens = rowResult.split(delims, -1);
            for (String t : tokens){

                System.out.println("j: " + j + "t: " + t);

                if (j == 1){ ... }
                else if (j==2){ ... }
                                ...

                j++;
            }
            j=0;
        }
    }
```

"[,()\"]+" works fine for non-zero length values. I'm able to pick up the right sub-string according to index value j. I've read that passing a negative value to split(, ) will not discard the non-zero length values ... but it does. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you could try with `.split("[()\"]*,{1}[()\"]*")`;

The expression user before `[,()\"]+` will use as separator more than one comma or any other separator informed. For instance `,,` will be consider one, so does `[],[]`. The expression commented above, expects that zero or more of the separators are followed with just one comma and this can be followed with zero or more separators too.

Comment: This works well! Only problem is opening and closing parenthesis in at the start and end of the string to be split appear in the first and last split elements.                                          `rowresult: (74,"and there","is a car","in the","garage man",t)
j: 0t: (74
j: 1t: and there
j: 2t: is a car
j: 3t: in the
j: 4t: garage man
j: 5t: t)`

Comment: Couldn't this parenthesis be removed manually? Like:
`if (str.startsWith("(")) str = str.substring(1);` and
`if (str.endsWith(")")) str = str.substring(0, str.length()-1);` before execute the split?

Comment: and maybe you could use the same strategy using replace, this would facilitate a bit... for instance `String str = "(74,\"and there\",\"is a car\",\"in the\",\"garage man\",t)"; if (str.startsWith("(")) str = str.substring(1); if (str.endsWith(")")) str = str.substring(0, str.length()-1); String result = str.replaceAll("[()\"]*,{1}[()\"]*","|");`

Comment: Thank you Spaeth. Will confirm this after lunch, but I think I know what to do. Will post answer as well.

Comment: There is a small problem with .split("[()\"]*,{1}[()\"]*"). If an input is as such: `"final test",f,12`, the first double quote " is added to the first split String: `j: 0; t: "final test
j: 1; t: f
j: 2; t: 12` How can I change the delimiter string in order for this to work? Note that it works fine when the double quoted String isn't the first element before splitting: `20,"Store Lusaka",,,,t` outputs: `j: 0; t: 20
j: 1; t: Store Lusaka
j: 2; t: 
j: 3; t: 
j: 4; t: 
j: 5; t: t` Please let me know if I'm not clear ... Thanks again.

Comment: Note that I've added this line before the split: `rowResult = rowResult.replace("\"", "");` and it works just fine. But thats an extra line of code in what is supposed to be something like google's auto-suggest, so performance is crucial.

Answer (score 0):

Why have you not used [String.replace or replaceall](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29), it will work as your current program, but if you need to skip empty parts of string you should firstly

- create String builder
- append all data from input array list (with condition if data length  == 0 or data is null just skip it)
- last append your symbol |

Comment: Thanks. Will look into it and post as soon as I have worked on it.

Answer (score 0):

The `int` parameter of `split()` means the max length of the result array. So I think you should determine it use method `String#isempty()` by yourself.

See more detail:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String, int)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Spaeth. This is working they way I need it to. Sorry for my adding the pipes in my original question. I just typed them in order to separate the elements. I needed the elements according to their specific indexes, defined by the commas, in order to maintain the columns from the resultset.

```
public void refreshSearchTable (ArrayList<String> newData){
        int noOfRows = newData.size();
        int noOfColumns = gui.getTableSearchResultHeader().length + 2;
        Object[][] tempList = new Object[noOfRows][noOfColumns];
        String rowResult = "";
        String delims = "[()\"]*,{1}[()\"]*";
        String [] tokens;
        Object [] elements = newData.toArray();

        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < noOfRows; i++){
            rowResult = elements[i].toString();
            if (rowResult.startsWith("(")){
                rowResult = rowResult.substring(1);
            }
            if (rowResult.endsWith(")")){
                rowResult = rowResult.substring(0, rowResult.length()-1);
            }
            System.out.println("rowresult: " + rowResult);
            tokens = rowResult.split(delims);
            for (String t : tokens){

                System.out.println("j: " + j + "t: " + t);

                j++;
            }
            j=0;
        }
```

Output:

```
rowresult: 74,"and there","is a car","in the","garage man",t
j: 0t: 74
j: 1t: and there
j: 2t: is a car
j: 3t: in the
j: 4t: garage man
j: 5t: t
```